# how to create a multilevel dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

It must be a simple thing but can't get my head around it. Part of my script does this:

```
myDict = {}
for dev in self.dmd.Devices():
    device = dev.id
    collector = dev.getPerformanceServerName()
    instances = [ inst.id for inst in dev.instances() ]
```

and from there, I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "EC2-test-eip-alloc": {
        "mon511.backbc.local": [
            "i-1828ca57",
            "i-372d3978"
        ]
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

where *EC2-test-eip-alloc* => `device`, *mon511.backbc.local* => `collector` and *["i-1828ca57","i-372d3978"]* => `instances`. I tried with:

```
inDict = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), device, myDict)
inDict.setdefault(collector, instances)
```

but getting a very strange result, where every character of `device` is being taken as keys, like this:
`{"E":{"C":{"2":{"-":{...}}}}}`. Any idea how can I get this thing right? cheers!!

Comment: The `reduce` is iterating over `device`, which is a string.  Not sure how to fix it yet, but maybe that helps.

Comment: In the `reduce`, you could wrap `device` in a tuple: `(device,)`

Comment: @Bill: Thanks! I already tried, `(device)` but not with the `,` in the end. Worked just fine. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate my comment above, change

```
inDict = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), device, myDict)
```

to

```
inDict = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), (device,), myDict)
```

so that reduce iterates through `('device', )` (which yields `'device', StopIteration`) instead of 'device' (which yields `'d', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'c', 'e', StopIteration`).